# Night vision led

Tags: led

What is the best night vision (type not brand) IR Led for night vision on a car camera for driving at high speeds without headlights?  (I'M A RALLY DRIVER BTW AND SOMETIMES HEADLIGHT GET DAMAGED AND WE HAVE TO DRIVE BLIND) Sorry I'm new to this, but I will be needing design and wiring diagrams to follow this question if that's aloud. Things like resistor etc

Comment: Welcome to SE EE, unfortunately we don't do product recommendations here. This site is about electronics design. Also SHOUTING is frowned upon here.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, but I will be needing design and wiring diagrams to follow this question if that's aloud. Things like resistor etc

Comment: Why wouldn't you use white LEDs?

Comment: We do but  we have accidents and the lamps break the ir's will be along the inside (top) of windscreen. Rallying has a lot of rules and regulations with what we can use I normally stick to the osram range of bulbs

Comment: Your design only draws 1W which won’t give clear vision unless you have military night vision goggles and even only a range of about .1 second in front you at rally speeds.  Get  100W light bar with narrow beam lens. A handheld flashlight out the window could be 10W to 100W

Comment: infrared illuminators using Total Internal Reflection technology to boost LED light efficiency. This proprietary design allows for evenly distributed illumination with viewing distance over 400 meters (1320ft). Another advantage of these illuminators is the low power consumption, 60W only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like a 3W IR LED would probably be a good option. There are some going on EBay for £2:08 but I am unsure what the quality of those would be like. You can then just use an adjustable voltage constant current driver that could plug into a range of voltage supplies.

A standard white 3W LED would probably still be preferable

Note: If you search LM2596 on EBay, You can find something that should be suitable and you can simply search 3W IR LED to find one of those

Comment: I've tried these been told they are the best type but I'm not satisfied Lenses Type : Crystal Clear

Case Style : 5mm Round

Forward Voltage : 1.5v - 1.6v

Forward Current : 60mA

Wavelength : 850nm

Comment: You will probably struggle to get much brighter. Otherwise night CCTV Cameras often have decent IR LED Arrays which could be useful in your application. Especially as they will be optimised for image capture in the dark.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, is there a diagram or drawing and no of things and parts I will need. About 1000mm length and 3"in width that's the legal maximum window to drivers viewing point that's aloud on my car. Thanks

Comment: If you are referring to the 3W High Power LED Lamp Infrared IR or an IR LED with wavelengths of 730-740, these are not IR they are far red.  You need to match wavelength of the LED  to the wavelength of the camera.

Comment: A bit more digging on EBay found some LED IR Spotlights meant for CCTV usage. They have an wavelength on 850nm and have a physical diamiter of approximately 70mm. They seem like they would be appropriate for your application as they run directly off 12v meaning you could power them from your car's supply. In terms of wiring, a small peice of terminal block and an old cigarette lighter plug would probably be sufficient. If it was me, this is what I would use so I hope it helps.